# How to show the progress bar on dask DataFrame.iterrows

Tags: python, pandas, dask, tqdm

I try to show the progress bar while using iterrows on dask. However, it only show (which I assumed) for the first loop progress bar.

```
 import dask.array as da
 import dask.dataframe as dd
 from dask.diagnostics import ProgressBar
 from tqdm.auto import tqdm
 
 # Create a Dask array with many rows of data
 data = da.ones((10000, 1))
 
 # Convert the Dask array to a Dask DataFrame with a single column
 df = dd.from_dask_array(data, columns=['value'])
 
 with ProgressBar():
     for i, row in df.iterrows():
         process(row)
```

I expect it to show the progress bar for the whole loop

Comment: Using `iterrows` on a `dask.dataframe` is definitely an anti-pattern.

Comment: ^ THIS Is the answer: please clarify what you are actually wanting to achieve.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of it. However, I don't see any other way to do it using dask. I will create separate SO question on it

Answer (score 1):

**Update**
The goal of `ProgressBar` is not the same as `tqdm`. Try this to see the difference:

```
import dask as ds
import dask.array as da
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.diagnostics import ProgressBar
import time

data = da.random.randint(1, 100, (10000, 2))
df = dd.from_dask_array(data, columns=['x', 'y'])

@ds.delayed
def taskA(df):
    time.sleep(1)
    return df['x'] * df['y']

@ds.delayed
def taskB(sr):
    time.sleep(1)
    return sr / 100
        
with ProgressBar():
    ds.compute(taskB(taskA(df)))
```

---

You can try:

```
import dask.array as da
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.diagnostics import ProgressBar
from tqdm.auto import tqdm
 
# Create a Dask array with many rows of data
data = da.ones((10000, 1))
 
 # Convert the Dask array to a Dask DataFrame with a single column
df = dd.from_dask_array(data, columns=['value'])
 
for i, row in tqdm(df.iterrows(), total=len(df)):
   process(row)
```

Output:

```
100%|███████████████████████████████████████████████| 10000/10000 [00:00<00:00, 34659.83it/s]
```

Comment: Do you mean, dask ProgressBar only works on delayed functions?